# как отловить событие изменения размера столбца в QTableWidget?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt5, qt5

У меня есть `QTableWidget`, пользователь может менять размер столбцов при помощи мыши, и мне бы хотелось иметь возможность отловить какой-нибудь сигнал при изменении размеров какого-нибудь столбца.

Но в `QTableWidget` нет никаких сигналов, которые бы делали то, что я хочу.

Где мне искать нужный сигнал?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648999/qtablewidget-column-resize-event

Comment: Боюсь показаться банальным, но в документации https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sectionResized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отслеживания размера столбцов в заголовке таблицы, нужно обратиться к `horizontalHeader` и подключиться к его сигналу `sectionResized`:

- [QHeaderView::sectionResized(int logicalIndex, int oldSize, int newSize)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sectionResized)

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget

def _on_section_resized(logical_index: int, old_size: int, new_size: int):
    print(logical_index, old_size, new_size)

app = QApplication([])

table = QTableWidget()
table.setColumnCount(5)
table.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.connect(_on_section_resized)
table.resize(600, 400)
table.show()

app.exec()
```

Если подключение сигнала будет к методу:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QMainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        table = QTableWidget()
        table.setColumnCount(5)
        table.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.connect(self._on_section_resized)

        self.setCentralWidget(table)

    def _on_section_resized(self, logical_index: int, old_size: int, new_size: int):
        print(logical_index, old_size, new_size)

app = QApplication([])

mw = MainWindow()
mw.resize(600, 400)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```